# C++ Clipboard entries keep overwriting instead of having separate entries

Tags: c++, memory, clipboarddata

I am writing a program that takes all objects from a JSON array and copies them into the clipboard. However, when I open the Clipboard history only the last object from the file is shown, therefore they keep overwriting each other.

This is my Code:

```
void loadOldClipboard() {
    // Load the JSON data from our File
    std::ifstream file("pastEntries.json");
    Json::Value root;
    file >> root;
    file.close();
    OpenClipboard(0);
    EmptyClipboard();
    for (const auto& obj : root) {
        std::string entry = obj["clipboardEntry"].asString();
        std::cout << "clipboardEntry: " << entry << std::endl;

        // Allocate global memory for the clipboard data
        HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, entry.size() + 1);
        if (hMem == NULL) {
            // Handle memory allocation error
            CloseClipboard();
            return;
        }

        // Copy the entry to the global memory
        char* pMem = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hMem));
        if (pMem == NULL) {
            // Handle memory locking error
            GlobalFree(hMem);
            CloseClipboard();
            return;
        }
        strcpy_s(pMem, entry.size() + 1, entry.c_str());
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);

        // Set the clipboard data for the current entry
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
    }
    CloseClipboard();
}
```

just in case I also added my current JSON File:

```
[
    {
        "clipboardEntry": "Entry 1"
    },
    {
        "clipboardEntry": "Entry 2"
    },
    {
        "clipboardEntry": "Entry 3"
    }
]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried opening and closing the clipboard on each loop iteration, but it still doesn't work.

```
void loadOldClipboard() {
    // Load the JSON data from our File
    std::ifstream file("pastEntries.json");
    Json::Value root;
    file >> root;
    file.close();

    // Allocate global memory for each string and copy it to the clipboard
    for (const auto& text : root) {
        if (!OpenClipboard(0)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open clipboard\n";
            return;
        }

        // Empty the clipboard
        EmptyClipboard();

        std::string entry = text["clipboardEntry"].asString();
        std::cout << "clipboardEntry: " << entry << std::endl;
        // Allocate global memory for the clipboard data
        HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, entry.size() + 1);
        if (hMem == NULL) {
            // Handle memory allocation error
            CloseClipboard();
            return;
        }

        // Copy the text to the global memory
        char* pMem = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hMem));
        if (pMem == NULL) {
            // Handle memory locking error
            GlobalFree(hMem);
            CloseClipboard();
            return;
        }
        strcpy_s(pMem, entry.size() + 1, entry.c_str());
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);

        // Set the clipboard data
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);

        // Close the clipboard
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I got it to work, it turns out that similar to what @Halfix mentioned, I needed to put in a `Sleep()` delay of around 1/2 - 1 second. Otherwise, the program couldn't process it properly.

Comment: I haven't dealt with clipboard history on code level so far, but if it doesn't work the way you do it currently I would try putting the OpenClipboard()/CloseClipboard() bracket into the for-loop (open/close the clipboard for each single data-push) and maybe add some sleep-delay into each loop-cycle, to give the clipboard system some time to process your changes.

Comment: @Halfix Still nothing, I'm relatively new to c++ but I believe it may have something to do with the memory allocate

Comment: Just on a side note, `CF_TEXT` deals with ANSI text, but JSON deals with Unicode text, so I would suggest using `CF_UNICODETEXT` instead, storing the text using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`. If you must use `CF_TEXT`/`std::string` that at least include `CF_LOCALE` to indicate the actual encoding of the `std::string` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @MarioRütsche didn't show the final code himself, I took it upon myself. I quickly recreated it and ended up with this new function. It looks like the problem was indeed with the built-in Clipboard Viewer from Windows not properly receiving the Data, so I added a `Sleep()` of 1 second.

```
void loadOldClipboard() {
    // Load the JSON data from our File
    std::ifstream file("pastEntries.json");
    Json::Value root;
    file >> root;
    file.close();


    // Allocate global memory for each string and copy it to the clipboard
    for (const auto& text : root) {
        if (!OpenClipboard(0)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open clipboard\n";
            return;
        }

        // Empty the clipboard
        EmptyClipboard();

        std::string entry = text["clipboardEntry"].asString();
        std::cout << "clipboardEntry: " << entry << std::endl;
        // Allocate global memory for the clipboard data
        HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, entry.size() + 1);
        if (hMem == NULL) {
            // Handle memory allocation error
            CloseClipboard();
            return;
        }

        // Copy the text to the global memory
        char* pMem = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hMem));
        if (pMem == NULL) {
            // Handle memory locking error
            GlobalFree(hMem);
            CloseClipboard();
            return;
        }
        strcpy_s(pMem, entry.size() + 1, entry.c_str());
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);

        // Set the clipboard data
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);

        HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
        char* pszData = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hData));
        std::string clipboardContent = pszData;

        // Close the clipboard
        CloseClipboard();
        Sleep(1000); // Wait for 1000ms before checking again
    }
 }
```

Comment: My theory: This is not an issue of the clipboard itself. The clipboard can process updates at any speed and would just reject the next open() if the previous touch was not fully processed. It's solely a problem of the history tool. I assume this tool is independent of the clipboard service and just uses public clipboard interfaces and therefore relies on periodic polling to pick up new clipboard content. That's exactly what my own homegrown clipboard history tool does as well and my own tool fails exactly like the Win+V Windows feature on clipboard changes faster than my poll interval.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.  Until you call `CloseClipboard()`, the data is not fully committed (ie, other apps can't access it).  The clipboard allows code to call `SetClipboardData()` multiple times with *different* types of data, and then commit them in one go. But, since you are setting only `CF_TEXT` on every iteration, `CloseClipboard()` will commit only the last item that you set.

If you want the clipboard history to record every `CF_TEXT` item individually, you will have to (re-)open/close the clipboard on each iteration.

Comment: I am still experiencing the same issue, I have been trying to fix this for about a week now and cannot find anything. You can take a look at the updated code in my original question if you want to.

Comment: @MarioRütsche please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing comments/answers. I have rolled back and tweaked your edit to preserve the original question. Also, your final update about the sleep delay should have been posted as its own answer rather than as an edit to the question, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @MarioRütsche "*I needed to put in a `Sleep()` delay of around 1/2 - 1 second. Otherwise, the program couldn't process it properly*" - which "program" are you referring to? You are not using the clipboard for inter-process communication, are you? Or, are you just referring to the built-in clipboard history viewer (Winkey + V)?